# how to store a box2d b2FixtureDef fixtureDefinition into a NSArray in Xcode

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, box2d

I've got some issues wrapping an application, developed through netbeans 8 in html5 and javascript, into PhoneGap to make it playable also on iOS devices.
So (since it's anyway a matter i want to learn) I'm trying a port to the iOS native Objective-C language in Xcode.

I could already re-write some Javascript functions, but as I came in need to store some of my Box2D objects and structs into arrays or dictionaries I started to feel lost.

my situation is like this:

in Javascript i can make arrays to store all the objects and fixtures i need to create in this way:

```
function createBoxStart(){

        //create three objects when game starts
        for (i = 0; i < '...number of objects i need'; i++) {

        var start = {x: '...some operation to get my x',
                     y: '...some operation to get my y'};

        var fixDefContainer = new Array();
        fixDefContainer['fixDef'+prodNum] = new box2d.b2FixtureDef;

        fixDefContainer['fixDef'+prodNum].density = 10;
        fixDefContainer['fixDef'+prodNum].friction = 10 ;
        fixDefContainer['fixDef'+prodNum].restitution = myBox[prodNum].reflection;

        var bodyDefContainer = new Array();
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum] = new box2d.b2BodyDef();

        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].type = box2d.b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].position.x = start.x /scale;
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].position.y = start.y /scale;
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].gravityScale = myBox[prodNum].g;
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].linearDamping = myBox[prodNum].lDamp;
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].angularDamping = myBox[prodNum].angDamp;
        bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum].userData = coinBox[prodNum].userName ;
        fixDefContainer['fixDef'+prodNum].shape = new box2d.b2CircleShape(coinBox[prodNum].size/scale);

        myBody[prodNum] = bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum];
        myBody.id = myBody[prodNum].userData;


        myObj[prodNum] = world.CreateBody(bodyDefContainer['bodyDef'+prodNum]);
        myObj[prodNum].CreateFixture(fixDefContainer['fixDef'+prodNum]);


        prodNum++;


        .....
        ..... }...}
```

However in Xcode I've to create a "NSArray* myArray" object, and also, as long I've made it, I found out I cannot store any C++ objects into it without wrapping them before.
I'm still trying to make it work using the NSValue class as i saw in some tutorials, but also i totally don't know yet how to store the fixtures, since they're neither initialized with a  pointer.

Here is how i create the "myFixDef" object, and since it has not a "*" i cannot wrap it into the NSVAlue class.

```
    b2FixtureDef myFixDef;
```

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A b2FixtureDef is really just a collection of properties like friction, restitution, density etc. You can store that in an Obj-C structure if it's easier, and then just set the properties in a b2FixtureDef when you need to create a fixture.

Comment: Thanks, it can work but I need to set it in a dynamic way: I tried to use a struct like this: struct fixtureDef { 'my stuff'}; struct fixtureDef; myFixture[myDynamicIntVar]; but even before set properties it gives me error due to need of a constant

Comment: All solved, i just simplified, just storing the resulted b2Body* into a NSArray through NSValue wrapping.